# How to extract the minimal value from NMinimize?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, numerical-value

According to the manual, if I calculate

```
NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x]
```

that returns {-3.51391, {x -> 1.30084}}, I can extract the minimal value -3.51391 using

```
x /. Last[NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 + x, x]]
```

Now, if I want to calculate e.g.

```
NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x + y^2, {x,y}]
```

then how do I extract the minimal value?

Comment: Look at [`NMinValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NMinValue.html) and [`NArgMin`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NArgMin.html)

Comment: `data = NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x + y^2, {x, y}];
First@data`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want to find what the minimum value of the expression is then this

```
First[NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x, x]]

(*-3.5139*)
```

If you mean that you want both the x and y values that minimize the expression then this

```
{x,y}/.Last[NMinimize[x^4 - 3 x^2 - x + y^2, {x,y}]]

(*{1.3008, 0.}*)
```

And  you can do even more interesting things, you can put any expression in front of that `/.` and then every x and y value inside that expression will be replaced by the values of x and y found by `NMinimize`, whether the expression is a list or anything else.